# random value from php variable to jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

My problem is that I need to be able to use random values from `index.php´  in a`jquery`function. I'm kind of stuck in the process.

I have an `sql` table that contains two columns `country` and `dish`.

In my  `index.php` I call the data-base and import the value to an array witch gives my random selection from the database. I store that in two variables `$country` and `$dish`

```
<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT country, dish FROM countries_dishes ORDER BY id';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $dishes = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $random_countries = $dishes[array_rand($dishes)];

    $country = $random_countries['country'];
     $dish = $random_countries['dish'];
 ?>
```

Then I load the php variables in my `script.js` like so:

```
var randCountries = <?php echo json_encode($country); ?>;
var randDish = <?php echo json_encode($dish); ?>;

console.log(randCountries);
console.log(randDish);

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#btn-select').click(function(){

   var country = randCountries;
   var dish = randDish;
   console.log(country);
 });


});
```

when I refresh the page I can see random values from `console.log(randCountries);` and `console.log(randDish);`

but the `console.log(country);` is always showing `Antartica` when the `#btn-select` button is clicked.

The thing is that I don't want to refresh the page each time to get random values. I need to be able to get the random values from  `var randCountries` and `var randDish` to the jquery function in some way or another.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Why is it showing `Antartica`? Is this a default value or the first in the table?

Comment: it's the first in the table

Comment: AJAX, you need to call the php via js on click, for that you need AJAX